# Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm a new learner to express js and sequelizejs. I successfully migrate table in my database so the connection is fine I guess.

Here is my code.
https://github.com/Picks42/express-test
Please review this file 
https://github.com/Picks42/express-test/blob/master/models/user.js

Then review this one 
https://github.com/Picks42/express-test/blob/master/controller/test.js

Let me know what's the issue.

Comment: I think it's obvious as I can not see models too and it's trying models.user.findAll, also you have defined variable M_Bank. Or maybe you imported wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// all the models using your index.js loader
const models = require('../models');
// the user model, note the capital User since 
const M_Bank = models.User;

exports.getTest = function(req,res){
    return M_Bank
    .findAll()
    // don't use M_Bank here since you are getting an array of Instances of the Model
    .then(users => res.status(200).send(users))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.toString());
      res.status(400).send(error)
    });

    /* this will never execute because it is after the return
    exports.index = function (request, response, next) {
        response.json((M_Bank.findAll()));
    };
    */
};
```

If you have the option of using `async/await` it makes for more readable code.

```
const models = require('../models');
const M_Bank = models.User;

exports.getTest = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const users = await M_Bank.findAll();
    return res.status(200).send(users);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.toString());
    return res.status(400).send(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the .User field in the 3rd line. because you've exported User itself from the `models/user` file.
Also, I recommend you not to mess with variables names. M_Bank variable doesn't speak itself

```
const M_Bank = require('../models/user');
exports.getTest = function(req,res){
    return M_Bank
    .findAll()
    .then(M_Bank => res.status(200).send(M_Bank))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.toString());
      res.status(400).send(error)
    });
    exports.index = function (request, response, next) {
        response.json((M_Bank.findAll()));
    };
};
```

Comment: If I use what you said it is giving me this error
http://prntscr.com/o46h7y
Updated code
http://prntscr.com/o46hdr

Comment: Also when I debug with my code if found this 
http://prntscr.com/o46ixr

Comment: The `require` here is returning the unloaded Model definition, you have to fetch it via the index.js loader once it is loaded into Sequelize - `const M_Bank = require('../models').User;`